Adobe Illustrator Paste on All Artboards
Maybe, I'm using it wrong, however, when I use 'Paste on All Artboards' it also pastes onto the artboard that I copied the object from. I understand that is technically what "All" means, but why would you want to paste on the artboard you are working on?

Looking at it from a dev standpoint...
A "Paste on All Artboards Except the Active Artboard" menu item is too long and would be utterly confusing for many users. As is "Paste on all Artboards Including Active Artboard". So there's that. Just makes sense to use "Paste on All Artboards".
Regarding functionality...
If the Active artboard was ignored for the paste... users who want the paste to include the active artboard would be frustrated - and there'd be no way to work around such behavior. In addition, if "all Artboards" were not included this could lead to user confusion.. e.g. why does the command state "all" if it's not actually "all"?
So I believe Adobe spit the baby...
It only takes a moment to learn to use Edit > Cut, rather than Edit > Copy, if the intent is to then paste on all artboards. This is a minor workaround that really just means you use the x key rather than the c key. It allows users to paste (a duplicate) on the active artboard if that's the desire, and it adheres to the "all" logic.

So counter point as a dev myself, "Paste on Other Artboards" is only 2 characters longer...however, I will concede that I didn't even think about Cut then Paste on All Artboards. I typically drag or delete and rarely use Cut outside of working with text.
Thank you!

Paste on Other hadn't occurred to me. Good point. But I still think skipping the active artboard would be confusing for users. And, believe it or not, I think "other" would cause some users to ask what "other" means. I know it seems obvious, but, well.... - And for the record, this is one of the few times I myself will use Cut.

Agreed, with using Cut instead of Copy, "Past on All Artboards" does what I want and would be less confusing. Thanks!

Pasting something onto every Artboard would make sense for something you are bringing into an Illustrator document from elsewhere (even from another Illustrator document).
If you are pasting something from inside the document you are working on, then it would be better to use the Cut command rather than the Copy command.
You are correct- the Paste on all Artboards will Paste it onto every Artboard- even onto the artboard you copied it from.

Thank you for your reply!
